# Scatter Plot with rows as individual series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have many rows that need to be plotted in a scatter plot as individual series.

C2;C55 contain the names of each individual series which I would like to label in the scatter plot.

Z2;Z55 contain the x values for each individual series

Y2;Y55 contain the y values for each individual series

Is there a way to quickly plot each individual series with out selecting data from the cross plot and selecting out each individual series?

Thanks for your time and insight. I am impressed with this site. First time asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

This routine inserts a new sheet, and adds each row as a new series with X values in column Z, Y values in column Y, and series names in column C, with each point labeled with its series name:

```
Sub MakeMyChart()
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter).Chart
    Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
      .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    Dim RowNum As Long
    For RowNum = 2 To 55
      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & RowNum)
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & RowNum)
        .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Range("C" & RowNum).Address(, , , True)
        .HasDataLabels = True
        With .DataLabels
          .ShowValue = False
          .ShowSeriesName = True
        End With
      End With
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```